# update textbox from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, textbox

I'm in the process of converting an application into an ASP.NET Website. The way the page works is that the user puts in a list of machines in the box then click start, it goes through the list runs the checks and outputs the status and results to a text box on the left. In addition it puts a processing icon beside the check mark as it runs a check and removes it when the check is done. In my .NET application it works fine, but I can't figure out how to do it in ASP.NET

I've tried using Ajax controls to do this so I enclosed the status box in an update panel and put a timer that updates the panel every second.

In the code behind, right now I have a function that just rights out some test text to the results text panel, along with a 3 second pause to simulate the code in the back ground. However it doesn't update the panel until the function finishes instead of each time the text is updated.

In classic ASP I would have written the status out to either a text file or a DB and just set the page to reload on a regular basis and retrieve the information until done flag was hit and then stop the reloads. I was trying to avoid making all those call backs if I could help it. I was hoping there was a better way to do it, but if there isn't I could make just the update panel call back but I'm still not entirely sure how to turn the processing icons on and off.

Page Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default4.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default4" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <table class="Standard">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="Title">
                        Title
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Column1">
                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                        Input Devices to Check<br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMachineList" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="12"
                            Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnStart" CssClass="button_blue_small" runat="server" Text="Start" OnClick="StartCheck" /><br />
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkOne" Text="Check 1" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Image ID="Load1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/flower-loader.gif" Visible="false" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkTwo" Text="Check 2" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Image ID="Load2" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/flower-loader.gif" Visible="false" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td class="Column2">Status:<br />

                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="StatusPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="StatusPanelTimer" EventName="Tick" />
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStatus" runat="server" Columns="300" Enabled="True" ReadOnly="True"
                                Width="800px" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="35"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Timer ID="StatusPanelTimer" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="StatusTimer_Tick"></asp:Timer>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
    protected void StartCheck(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    Load1.Visible = true;
    Load2.Visible = true;
    txtStatus.Text = "Test 1";

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    txtStatus.Text += "Test 2";

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    txtStatus.Text += "Test 3";

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Load1.Visible = false;
    Load2.Visible = false;
}
protected void StatusTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StatusPanel.Update();
}
```

Comment: Put the `Timer` into the `UpdatePanel`'s `ContentTemplate` and remove `UpdateMode="Conditional"` That's how I have mine, with a similar setup, updating every second.

Comment: Did that change anything?

Comment: @kschieck - I got a client side error message of - Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID 'StatusPanel' when UpdateMode is set to Conditional.

Comment: @kschieck I changed the update mode back to conditional and the client side error went away, but it still doesn't update till the whole function is complete.

Comment: Did you mean to set the interval set to `10000`? In your question you mentioned that it is supposed to refresh every second and `10000` is actually 10 seconds.

Comment: @kschieck - I caught that too, it should be 1000, which should make the panel update at least 9 times, but I still don't see updated text till the start check function is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the problem is in your "Start" button's function.

If you just add:

```
txtStatus.Text += "Tick\n";
```

to your tick event, you can see that your page is updating.

The problem is that After you click the button, the page doesn't receive a response until the `StartCheck` function finishes (Even the ticking stops).

Comment: Ok, this makes sense now that I see it. I'll have to figure out how I want to handle this knowing that.